# Override ToString method in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, partial-classes

This is my service generated class:

```
public partial class MyClass : object, 
                               System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, 
                               System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ }
```

I'm using my own service. In `MyClass` I have overridden `ToString()` but I don't have it in my client. I want either to generate it or as `MyClass` is partial am I able to override `ToString` myself?

I know that I can write in generated .cs file. What is the best way to do it and at all should I do it?

Comment: WCF will generate a client-side proxy class that has the same **XML signature** when serialized/deserialized - but that does **NOT** "propagate" any methods (strictly only data - your class' public properties) from the server to the client.

Comment: tha i see but how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are defining both the client and the service, you don't need to use the WSDL-generate classes. Move the shared objects into a separate assembly, and reference it from both client and server projects. When you create the service reference, there's an "advanced" option (which I think is on by default) that reuses any known classes from the WSDL instead of generating new ones.

Even better, if you move the service contract into your shared library, you don't even need to create the service reference, you can just call the `ChannelFactory` directly and eliminate the entire auto-generated proxy class.

I have a demonstration on how to do both of these things on my blog: http://blog.kutulu.org/2012/03/proxy-free-wcf-ditching-proxy.html

If you absolutely *need* to use the WSDL from the service (e.g. you don't have control over the service side and it could change on you), then you can  extend the partial classes that VS creates (as you suggested). Most auto-generate classes you get from VS these days are partial classes specifically to make this kind of extension possible. The downside, of course, is that nothing guarantees client and server's additional partial class methods are the same. I'd definitely consider this a last-resort option.

Comment: can u explain me shortly why does that service generates partial class? for what reason?

Comment: Almost everything VS2010 generates automatically is partial classes, so you can extend them as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you share the dll where overriden method exixts between client and server project, you can use the method. By default, WCF generates each class with only properties declared in the service interface. No method is generated.

You can just create a seperate dll file and put what you want to share between service and client into this dll; and add this dll as a reference to both client and service projects. By default, when you generate the proxy, it will not auto generate the shared classes.